# Creepage distance get from UL840 note

Tags: creepage

I'm considering on creepage distances on my PCB. I have read [UL840](http://c-planners.com/UL840.pdf),there are two significant tables. 6.1 "Minimum acceptable creepage distances" and 6.2 "Minimum acceptable creepage distances on printed wiring boards". I have read post: [Trace width and clearance calculations](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102986/trace-width-and-clearance-calculations/103010#103010). I noticed that Dave Tweed recommends to use 6.2 table. But in table 6.1 there is a sentence: "Creepage distances for equipment subject to long-term stress". I'm considering what does it mean, and when i should use values from table 6.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between 6.1 and 6.2 is based on the continuous voltage differential between the traces.

**For example:** If you expect a continuous 1000V between two traces, it should be spaced according to 6.1.

If you only need to be able to withstand a 1000V surge infrequently and/or for brief periods of time, then the spacing can be according to 6.2.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but now i have new consideration. I design 27V circuit and creepage valu for this voltge from 6.1 is 0,53 mm. But on my PCB i have INA138NA/250 in SOT-23. Pin gnd and pin Vin are next to each other and the spacing beetwen them is 0,45 mm. I should think about milling?

Comment: What pollution levels are you expecting? You may not need to include spacing for level 2 if you don't expect level 2.  If you read note Z of table 1, it mentions that under 32V there isn't risk of tracking, simply corrosion.  I wouldn't be too concerned with the spacing at 27V, its fairly low and the component is clearly designed for it.